# System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Xamarin.Forms.Element.set_AutomationId' not found

Tags: xamarin.android

When I am making a Barcode Scanner Using ZXing Nuget Package. As I am new to the Xamarin, When I run it in the Xamarin.forms. I am receiving that error. I have the updated version of Xamarin.The program shows me the runtime Exception as mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 0):

This is more than likely due to the version of Xamarin.Forms that you are referencing. You need to make sure that your version of Xamarin.Forms is at least version 2.2, which has the AutomationId support.